# what can be a statement after if?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def check():
    if [1,2,3]:
        return [2,3,4]

check()
[2, 3, 4]
```

I thought `[1,2,3]` is a list but not a Boolean expression that can be True or False? But why does the function consider the list `([1,2,3])` to be True?

Comment: any [not-empty list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is considered true.

Comment: Any expression can be used where a boolean expression is required.

Comment: Check [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) to see what is considered true and false in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Any expression can be used as the condition in `if` or `while`. See https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html for how the truth value of the expression is evaluated.

Comment: wow, there is still documentation for python 2.4. :-)

Comment: Blame google, that's the page it found.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [python documentation on "Truth Value Testing"](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> The following values are considered false:
>
> [...]
>
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
>
> [...]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

So any not-empty list will be evaluated as `True` and any python object can be evaluated in a boolean context (if it doesn't throw an Exception in it's `__bool__` or `__len__` method, like for example `numpy.ndarray`).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, any expression of any type will be considered "True" unless it's an empty list/tuple, an empty string (which could technically also be considered a list of characters) or the number 0.

P.S. Just as a fun fact, the number 0.000001 returns True.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this ?

```
def checkList():
  if all(x in list2 for x in list1):
     return [ 2,3,4 ]
list1= [ 1,2,3 ]
list2= [ 1,2,3 ] 
print(checkList(list1,list2))
```

You really need this?SAnyway take a look here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing